# Libgdx Scrolling Background appearance of a line

Tags: java, android, libgdx, screen

I create a background using Inkscape and i use 2 same images of this background to show a moving background but a line appear between them when i run the game, any solutions ?

[Picture for the problem in a background the line appears and disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsAFO.jpg)

[Picture for the problem in another background ; the repeat of background is clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mV0N.jpg)

To clarify more this is my Background code :

```
public class Background extends Actor {


       private final TextureRegion textureRegion;
        private Rectangle textureRegionBounds1;
        private Rectangle textureRegionBounds2;
        private int speed = 70;

        public Background() {
            textureRegion = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_PATH)));
            textureRegionBounds1 = new Rectangle(-800/2, 0, 800,480);
            textureRegionBounds2 = new Rectangle(800/2, 0, 800, 480);
        }

        @Override
        public void act(float delta) {
            if (leftBoundsReached(delta)) {
                resetBounds();
            } else {
                updateXBounds(-delta);
            }
        }

         @Override
        public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
            super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
            batch.draw(textureRegion, textureRegionBounds1.x, textureRegionBounds1.y, 800,480);
            batch.draw(textureRegion, textureRegionBounds2.x, textureRegionBounds2.y, 800,480);
        }

        private boolean leftBoundsReached(float delta) {
            return (textureRegionBounds2.x - (delta * speed)) <= 0;
        }

        private void updateXBounds(float delta) {
            textureRegionBounds1.x += delta * speed;
            textureRegionBounds2.x += delta * speed;
        }

        private void resetBounds() {
            textureRegionBounds1 = textureRegionBounds2;
            textureRegionBounds2 = new Rectangle(800, 0, 800, 480);
        }

    }
```

in GameStage class Camera settings :

```
...
        private static final int VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 800;
        private static final int VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 480;
...
     public GameStage(){
            super(new ScalingViewport(Scaling.stretch, VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT,
                    new OrthographicCamera(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT)));
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
           // renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
            setUpWorld();
            setupCamera();

      }
...
private void setupCamera() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0f);
        camera.update();
    }
...
```

Comment: Are these images in a texture atlas, or are they loaded from separate image files at runtime? What texture filtering are you using?

Comment: thanks for your comment , i use TextureRegion , i edited my question u can understand me more

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calculating wrong because you got a column of black dots on right.

Be careful if you are calculating acording to right of the screen so its not will be width. It will be width-1 because x starting with a zero.

But this is not only error you have. But i cant guess other errors from just a picture.
It would be better if you provide some cod, filters you apply or original texture that you used.

Comment: thank you , I think the coordinates are correct , i edited my  question with a code

Answer (score 0):

Your `resetBounds()` method introduces error in the spacing between the two rectangular regions. When `leftBoundsReached()` returns true, the position of your region 2 bounds is not going to be an exact multiple of 400 or 800 or whatever spacing you're using. But `resetBounds()` creates a new set of bounds that are exactly at x = 800.

I would suggest something like this:

```
    private void resetBounds() {
        Rectangle tmp = textureRegionBounds1;
        textureRegionBounds1 = textureRegionBounds2;
        textureRegionBounds2 = tmp;
        textureRegionBounds2.x = textureRegionBounds1.x + textureRegionBounds1.width;
    }
```

By the way, I think your `act` method will produce a possibly visible stutter whenever the left bounds are reached, because you don't move the background on that frame. The background should be moved on every frame regardless if it's time to skip a rectangle over.

Comment: thank you for your answer , i try your resetBounds method but i stille have the same probelm of the line , plz if there are another solutions to get a good show for scrolling background tell me them